# OnDragListener not working properly

Tags: drag-and-drop

Hello everybody and thanks in advance.

I have a strange issue with one of my apps. This app is a MasterMind game which uses drag & drop, dragging coloured circles to holes.

This has been worked right with lots of devices, but recently I tried in a Galaxy S7 and Note 4 where the views(holes) have triggered the ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED outside the view.

Take a look at this screenshots to have a clearer idea...

< RIGHT BEHAVIOUR >

[image]

< WRONG BEHAVIOUR >

[image]

This is my listener...

```
    class MiDragListener implements OnDragListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
    {
        int accion = event.getAction();

        switch (accion)
        {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            v.setScaleX((float)1.0);
            v.setScaleY((float)1.0);
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            v.setScaleX((float)2.0);
            v.setScaleY((float)2.0);
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            v.setScaleX((float)1.0);
            v.setScaleY((float)1.0);
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
} // end MiDragListener
```

although my code has not been changed.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks for your time and attention.